# Debt management lawyer?

Tags: debt, fees, law

Is there such a thing as a debt management lawyer? I've got delinquent debts. I've got more than enough money to pay off all debts. I want to systematically look over each debt statement (fees, etc) and cut out any potentially excessive/unnecessary levies with the help of what I'm calling a "debt management lawyer."

Answer (score 3):

People who provide services like that are called debt councilors or debt advisors.

They help you to organize your debts, advise you in prioritizing them and also help you to negotiate or legally challenge any unreasonable levies.